# How can I invoke sp_prepexecrpc in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, odbc, wireshark

I'm currently trying to invoke  in SQL Server through ODBC. I tried executing queries like:

```
Declare @Out int;
EXEC  @Out output,
     N'@myNumber int',
     N'EXEC OdbcOneParameterProcedure @myNumber',
     @myNumber = 0;
EXEC  @Out;
```

and

```
DECLARE @Out int;

EXEC  @Out OUTPUT,
     N'OdbcOneParameterProcedure',
     @myNumber = 0;
SELECT @Out
```

But all I see is it was invoked in SQL Server as SQL Batch in packet trace in Wireshark. What else should I try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, one way of solving this is executing your StoredProcedure through PHP connector to ODBC using PDO

```
$odbcDataSource = 'dataSource';
$user = 'userName';
$password = 'userPassword';

$call = "{CALL OdbcOneParameterProcedure( ? )}";

$connection = new PDO($odbcDataSource, $user, $password);
if (!$connection) {
    echo 'Connection failed' . odbc_errormsg();
} else {
    echo 'Connected';

    $param = 0;

    $statement = $connection->prepare($call);
    $statement->bindParam(1, $param, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $statement->execute();

    // dump result to quickly verify correctness of query
    $result = $statement->fetchAll();
    var_dump($result);
}

$connection = null;
```